# Touchpad not working in ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron 15 7547

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad, inspiron

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my new Dell Inspiron 15 7547 properly. To my disappointment, the touchpad isn't working at all on ubuntu. However, it works fine on windows. Is there anyway I could get the touchpad to work by installing some driver or so? If not, is there any other Linux distribution that supports the touchpad on my Inspiron 7547? Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you add the output of `xinput list` to your question. You may learn something from reading the manpages for xinput (`man xinput`) and synclient (`man synclient`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Ubuntu 14.10 on my Dell Inspiron 7547, and the touchpad does work after boot. Problem is, it's not working after suspend/resume.

It might [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1384752).
People mentioned they didn't face this problem on later kernels. I've installed the [3.18 kernel](http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/803937-installupgrade-linux-kernel-to-3183-stable-in-ubuntulinux-mintpeppermint) and indeed the problem went away, for the most part. The touchpad was unresponsive once after resume (it was yesterday, yet to be seen if I can reproduce this).

For completeness, to answer the previous comment I'm also adding the `xinput list` output:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:75BD UNKNOWN             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset H760   id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I installed 3.17.1 and it works! But the right click doesn't work on the touchpad.. Does it work on 3.18?

Comment: I assume you mean clicking on the lower right side of the touchpad. It's not working for me either, it sends the leftclick event. I get around it by using the two-finger tap. It sends the rightclick event

Comment: @Tivoni concerning the Touchpad not working after a resume trying switching virtual terminals, that is `ctrl-alt-F8` to switch away then `ctrl-alt-F7` to switch back (assuming you started on the default F7). I sometime need to do that on an older Dell with a Synaptics Touchpad.

Comment: Update: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. Pressing on the right click area of the touchpad is now sending a right click event, so that's nice. Note that tapping that area is still sending a left click event. On the original subject, I've noticed the touchpad not reponding once after reboot (I had to reboot again to get it to work). On the surface of it, it looks like there's a stability regression from 14.10 + 3.18 kernel setup